# How to go to the next page with values after clicking ion-select

Tags: ionic-framework

I currently have this ion-select where once I click it it goes to the next page but it still shows the ion-select-option.

How do I remove it and get data from the next page back to the previous page?

here is what it looks like right now

```
<ion-select value="1" (click)=gotoClass()>
        <ion-select-option value="1" selected=true>1</ion-select-option>
 </ion-select> 
 </div>
```

and the next page

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-radio-group>
<ion-item>
  <ion-list>1</ion-list>
  <ion-radio value="1"></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-list>2</ion-list>
  <ion-radio value="2"></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-list>3</ion-list>
  <ion-radio value="3"></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-list>4</ion-list>
  <ion-radio value="4"></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-list>5</ion-list>
  <ion-radio value="5"></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Can you add push to next screen code here from your .ts file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ion-select` `(ionChange)` event like below:

```
<ion-select #ionselect value="1" (ionChange)="onSelectChange($event)">
    <ion-select-option value="1" selected=true>1</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

**.ts file:**

```
@ViewChild(ionselect) ionselect:Select;

onSelectChange(selectedValue: any) {
   //Before pushing to next dismiss your ion-select
   this.ionselect.close();
   //Push your new view here like 
   this.navCtrl.push(YourNextPage, {});
}
```

Before navigating to next screen you can close your ion-select.

Hope this will helps!